# Flutter multiple image provider invoke is increase the memory usage and leads to crash

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is the situation of Flutter application,

I have 100 images with full HD resolution and displaying those images on every swipe(Left or Right) in Flutter application.

After 10 to 15 images of display, suddenly the app gets disconnected or sometimes getting a crash. This image is loaded with the help of the "Image Provider" class.

```
 imageLocal = Image.file(File(com.getImagePath(entity))).image;
 imageLocal.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
          new ImageStreamListener((imageInfo, synchronousCall) {}));
```

Dart dev tools show an increase in memory in every image load(PFA). These cached images not clear until the app is closed.

[Dart Devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg90T.jpg)

I was tried to clear the cache also. But it's not working.

```
 PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
```

Flutter Details:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Looking for your advice or help of below problems,

1. Need to display more images(Large size images too) and for longer browsing duration without any slow and crash?
2. How to handle this external memory growth? (Probably this leads to app crash and slowness)
3. How to handle 8K images in a flutter with faster load time?

Your help is appreciated very much!!

Comment: have you found any est solutions on it? @pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) library as an image provider alongside [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) or [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) to display those images

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understood like the cached_network_image library for network image. Here the problem is with local image loading which increases RAM memory continuously.